# Creating a UDF in Java to map one dataframe column to another

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have written Scala code in spark-shell to map one column of a dataframe to another. I am now attempting to convert it to Java but am having difficulties with the UDF I defined.

I am taking this data frame:

```
+------+-----+-----+
|acctId|vehId|count|
+------+-----+-----+
|     1|  777|    3|
|     2|  777|    1|
|     1|  666|    1|
|     1|  999|    3|
|     1|  888|    2|
|     3|  777|    4|
|     2|  999|    1|
|     3|  888|    2|
|     2|  888|    3|
+------+-----+-----+
```

And converting it to this:

```
+------+----------------------------------------+
|acctId|vehIdToCount                            |
+------+----------------------------------------+
|1     |[777 -> 3, 666 -> 1, 999 -> 3, 888 -> 2]|
|3     |[777 -> 4, 888 -> 2]                    |
|2     |[777 -> 1, 999 -> 1, 888 -> 3]          |
+------+----------------------------------------+
```

I am doing this via these commands.
First, my UDF to map a list of row values from one column to a second column:

`val listToMap = udf((input: Seq[Row]) => input.map(row => (row.getAs[Long](0), row.getAs[Long](1))).toMap)`

I am doing this via a double groupBy/aggregation:

```
val resultDF = testData.groupBy("acctId", "vehId")
     .agg(count("acctId").cast("long").as("count"))
     .groupBy("acctId")
     .agg(collect_list(struct("vehId", "count")) as ("vehIdToCount"))
     .withColumn("vehIdToCount", listToMap($"map"))
```

My problem is in trying to write the listToMap UDF in Java. I am fairly new to both Scala and Java so I may just be missing something.

I was hoping I could do something as simple as:

```
UserDefinedFunction listToMap = udf(
        (Seq<Dataset<Row>> input) -> input.map(r -> (r.get(“vehicleId”), r.get(“count”)));
);
```

But I can not identify a valid method to get each of these columns, even after looking fairly extensively through the documentation. I have tried just doing a SELECT too but that is not working either.

Any help is much appreciated. For your reference this is how I’m generating my test data in spark-shell:

```
val testData = Seq(
    (1, 999),
    (1, 999),
    (2, 999),
    (1, 888),
    (2, 888),
    (3, 888),
    (2, 888),
    (2, 888),
    (1, 888),
    (1, 777),
    (1, 666),
    (3, 888),
    (1, 777),
    (3, 777),
    (2, 777),
    (3, 777),
    (3, 777),
    (1, 999),
    (3, 777),
    (1, 777)
).toDF("acctId", "vehId”)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you write the UDF, but I can show you how to avoid it using Spark's built-in `map_from_entries` function. UDFs should always be a path of last resort, both to keep your codebase simple and because Spark cannot optimize them. The below example is in Scala but should be trivial to translate:

```
scala> val testData = Seq(
     |     (1, 999),
     |     (1, 999),
     |     (2, 999),
     |     (1, 888),
     |     (2, 888),
     |     (3, 888),
     |     (2, 888),
     |     (2, 888),
     |     (1, 888),
     |     (1, 777),
     |     (1, 666),
     |     (3, 888),
     |     (1, 777),
     |     (3, 777),
     |     (2, 777),
     |     (3, 777),
     |     (3, 777),
     |     (1, 999),
     |     (3, 777),
     |     (1, 777)
     | ).toDF("acctId", "vehId")
testData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [acctId: int, vehId: int]

scala> 

scala> val withMap = testData.groupBy('acctId, 'vehId).
     | count.
     | select('acctId, struct('vehId, 'count).as("entries")).
     | groupBy('acctId).
     | agg(map_from_entries(collect_list('entries)).as("myMap"))
withMap: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [acctId: int, myMap: map<int,bigint>]

scala> 

scala> withMap.show(false)
+------+----------------------------------------+
|acctId|myMap                                   |
+------+----------------------------------------+
|1     |[777 -> 3, 666 -> 1, 999 -> 3, 888 -> 2]|
|3     |[777 -> 4, 888 -> 2]                    |
|2     |[777 -> 1, 999 -> 1, 888 -> 3]          |
+------+----------------------------------------+
```